# Difference between char* x and char* x[80]?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

What is the difference between   `char* x` and   `char* x[80]` ?

Comment: http://cdecl.org/ might help next time.

Answer (score 7):

`char * x` is a pointer to a char.

Means you can do operations like:-

```
char * x = "Hello World";
```

`char * x[80]` is an array of 80 elements, all of which are pointing to chars.
Means you can do something like this:-

```
x[0] = "This is number 1";
x[1] = "This is number 2";
x[2] = "Well it goes on!";
```

I hope it makes even more clear.

Answer (score 6):

`char* x` is a pointer to `char`.

`char* x[80]` is an array of 80 elements, the elements are pointers to `char`.

Answer (score 1):

`char a` :: `a` is a variable of type `char` which can store a character.

`char a[10]` :: 'a' is an array of 10 variables of type 'char' which can store a character.

Similarly,

`char* x` :: `x` is a variable of type `char*` **(Pointer to a char)** which can point to another variable of type `char`.

`char* x[80]` :: `x` is an **array of 80 variables** of type `char*` **(Pointer to a char)** which can point to another variable of type `char`.